# Creating a POS (Point of Sale) system with python

Tags: python, html, web-applications, web, web-deployment

I want to create a functional POS system with python, I just don't know where to begin. I am fluent in the language, but I have never done any web development with python. Can someone point me in the right direction, how to incorporate python into html and mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what POS means, is that Point of Sale?

For web development, people in Python land tend to go with Django and Flask as they are the most popular.

https://www.djangoproject.com/

and

http://flask.pocoo.org/

Comment: Yes it's point of sale :) Thanks for the links! What is better? I am learning towards django

Comment: Sure thing, be sure to select as answer if this answered your question.

Comment: What about for mysql integration?

Comment: Better is pretty subjective, although Flask is smaller than Django. I've used Django, and its pretty much a one stop shop for web dev. For MySQL integration, Django provides an ORM, object relational mapper, that takes care of integrating with a database.

Comment: Flask is good starting points